# Using the cp_custom_menu hook

Tags: add-on-development, hook

I can't get the cp_custom_menu hook to run. Here's my code. The activate_extension() function runs and successfully adds the extension to the db but it never gets called.

```
public function activate_extension()
{
    $hooks = array('cp_custom_menu');

    foreach ($hooks as $hook) {
        ee()->db->insert(
            'extensions',
            array(
                'class'    => __CLASS__,
                'hook'     => $hook,
                'method'   => $hook,
                'settings' => '',
                'priority' => 10,
                'version'  => $this->version,
                'enabled'  => 'y'
            )
        );
    }

}

public function cp_custom_menu($menu)
{
    // this never runs
    $menu->addItem('Title', ee('CP/URL')->make('/xyz'));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cp_custom_menu` hook, although *sounding* like it will automatically add an item to the menu, in fact just adds your add-on as a new option when creating a custom menu via **Settings -> Menu Manager** using the **Add-on** type. So check there before deciding that your function is never firing.

Comment: Ah you're right, I see it in the Menu manager list and that works when I add it.

Answer (score 1):

add this at the end of

```
public function cp_menu_array($menu)
    {
        if ($this->EE->extensions->last_call !== FALSE)
        {
            $menu = $this->EE->extensions->last_call;
        }

        $menu['whatever'] = cp_url('addons_modules/show_module_cp',array('module' => 'whatever'));
        $menu['whatever']       = BASE.AMP.'addons_modules/show_module_cp';
        return $menu;
    }
```

Comment: The people who find this answer would find it more helpful if you could add some explanatory text explaining what your code does.